# How do I change the opengl renderer to point to a different device?

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, opengl

My display driver points to one type of graphics chip and my OpenGL renderer points to another type of chip, despite me actually having a single integrated graphics card. When I look up the graphics card using lshw, it says:

```
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 09
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:28 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

glxinfo -B, which shows renderer-related information, however says:

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Intel (0x8086)
    Device: Mesa Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2) (0x162)
    Version: 22.0.0
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 1536MB
    Unified memory: yes
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.2
    Max compat profile version: 3.1
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.0
OpenGL vendor string: Intel
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.2 (Core Profile) Mesa 22.0.0-devel (git-b8f0459 2022-01-10 impish-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.20
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 22.0.0-devel (git-b8f0459 2022-01-10 impish-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL context flags: (none)

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 22.0.0-devel (git-b8f0459 2022-01-10 impish-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
```

How do I assign the renderer's device to `Intel Xeon E3-1200 v2` instead of `Intel HD Graphics 4000`?

Comment: The selection of the adaptor should be made in /etc/X11/xorg.conf or in some /etc/X11/xorg.d/*.conf file. Could you post xorg.conf and any possibly relevant xorg.d/*.conf file ?

Comment: Isn't the HD graphics part of the CPU?